# Aschroder Extensions having error 404 page not found

Tags: smtp

Form SMTP configuration I have added extention **Aschroder Extensions**. I have installed it. It is enabled too. But while selecting option I got error 404 page not found. Please help anybody knows. Version community edition 1.8 and 1.9 on both have tried.

Comment: Logout and login from magento admin and then try it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First verify that is it compatible with `Magento CE 1.8` and `Magento CE 1.9`. Clear all files under `var/cache`, log out and re-log into magento admin panel, and then try accessing that extension.

Comment: by clearing cache it starts working. Thanks for your precious reply.

Comment: My pleasure, buddy :)

Comment: If you can please will you guide me for Configuration. Any link or any video?

Comment: Configuration of what?

Comment: Actually I am configuring SMTP connection to send mail from localhost. I have configure Gmail to send mail through it. What are the settings to be set to send mail from magento project on localhost.

Comment: Well, I can't help you. I've not installed that extension. My suggestion is 'Sit and study the code used for development of that extension' or check support page in that extension page.

Comment: My pleasure....

Comment: Clearing the cache and logging out and back in worked for me.